# Mongoose - MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Fruit.find().then((fruits) => {
    console.log(fruits);
});
```

The piece of code above works perfectly fine, but I would like to add and if-else condition to it, which in older versions of mongoose looks something like

```
Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error occurred!');
    } else {
        console.log(fruits);
    }
});
```

Here's the error:

```
throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
    ^

MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback
```

I have the latest version of mongoDB, i.e. 7.0.

I want the result to throw a message stating 'error occurred!' if there's an error in fetching the data, and log the data otherwise.
Could someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Fruit.find()
  .then((fruits) => {
}).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

You can catch the error with like that. Mongoose no longer accept callbacks. Or you may look for try-catch blocks

```
try {
  const fruits = await Fruit.find({});
  console.log(fruits)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```